# Which pilot license is required in the US to engage in glider towing?

Tags: faa-regulations, glider, towing

As a former member of a US glider club (I live in Europe now, and it's all winch launches), I always thought being a tow pilot was a good way to build time. Can a private pilot tow gliders in exchange for money or credit with the club, or is a commercial ticket needed?

Comment: Are you specifically interested in whether the pilot can receive payment or requirements in general?

Comment: I'm in Canada and the only requirement at a private club is a PPL, and beyond that whatever the glider club requires (which will in part be based on insurance requirements).  Usually clubs want around 75-100TT with a tailwheel checkout of 5 hours or so.  For EASA, I believe they now have a towing rating of some kind, which you would probably get as a member of a club.  Google "EASA glider towing".  At a commercial glider center, common in the US, I believe may require a commercial license, but I think in Europe and UK like Canada it is almost all private clubs.

Comment: In the US a Private Pilot can receive compensation. Not sure about Europe. See the FAA Legal Interpretation for Umphres. https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/practice_areas/regulations/interpretations/data/interps/2010/umphres%20-%20(2010)%20legal%20interpretation.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A private pilot certificate is the minimum required.  In addition you need the following experience and endorsements to be current:

CFR, part 61, section 61.69, outlines the requirements for towing privileges.
You must:

> 1) Hold at least a private pilot certificate with the appropriate
>   category rating;
>
> 2) Have logged a minimum of 100 hours as pilot in command in the same
>   category aircraft used for towing;
>
> 3) Have a logbook endorsement from an authorized instructor certifying
>   you have received ground and flight training in gliders or unpowered
>   ultralight vehicles, and is proficient in the areas listed in part
>   61.69(a)(3)(i)(ii)(iii) and (iv);
>
> 4) Have a logbook endorsement from a pilot that already meets the
>   requirements of part 61.69 (c) and (d), who has accompanied the pilot
>   on three flights which has certified them to have accomplished at
>   least three flights in an aircraft while towing a glider or unpowered
>   ultralight vehicle, or while simulating towing flight procedures; and
>   In the preceding 12 months has performed three actual or simulated
>   tows accompanied by a qualified pilot or has been towed for three
>   flights in a glider or unpowered ultralight vehicle. In accordance
>   with part 61.52, pilots towing under an ultralight exemption may
>   credit experience obtained in ultralight vehicles for their towing
>   experience and endorsements.

Added per comment on question above:

Yes, a private pilot can be compensated for glider towing.

https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/practice_areas/regulations/interpretations/data/interps/2010/umphres%20-%20(2010)%20legal%20interpretation.pdf

Source: https://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/airmen_certification/sport_pilot/media/towing_req.pdf

Comment: Could you address the part about whether the pilot can receive payment?